# Getting GeoServer primary key metadata table working

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

I am having trouble getting a primary key field to be successfully accepted in GeoServer for spatial views (in PostgreSQL), with and without forcing it using the `gt_pk_metadata` table. I am seeking guidance on the sure fire steps to get this working correctly every time.

I know that this field has to be the first in the select statement, unless specifying the index in the `gt_pk_metadata` column. It also needs to be serial or a UUID, or unless forced by the `gt_pk_metadata` table. I have actually tested on both types of columns with mixed success.

We have some spatial views that originally had a `row_number() over()` column as the first column. This was accepted by QGIS, but not ArcGIS Pro (On Demand Mode) as it is not a primary key. To resolve this, I switched to using an actual primary key column from the main geometry table.  GeoServer seems sporadic in actually recognizing this column as a unique PK column (The generated GMLID is not using the column I want). Because of this I then started playing with the `gt_pk_metadata` table to try and force it. Again, with sporadic success.

First GeoServer does not seem to recognize that the primary key column we are selecting as the first column is not a unique primary key column even though it was created as `objectid SERIAL NOT NULL`, without setting the metadata table in the store. I'm not sure why this would be. At this point I'd like to force GeoServer using the `gt_pk_metadata` table to know that it's going to work in an expected way every time.

I have a few questions in regards to the `gt_pk_metadata table`, but please let me know if it is bad practice to ask multiple related questions:

1. Does this table belong in the public schema, or the schema to which you are storing data? The latter doesn't seem to make sense since the schema_name field would be redundant.
2. But if the table is in public, and you are connecting to a a different schema in the GeoServer store, does GeoServer still know to read that table from public?
3. Do I have to reset GeoServer for changes to take effect? Anyway of forcing a refresh without resetting? If I don't have to do these things, how long does it take for the changes to take affect?
4. The `pk_column_idx` is not required, but should it be filled out anyway? And confirming the index starts at 0.
5. Can I add other columns (`objectid`/`createuser`/etc) to this table without messing up GeoServer's internal processes?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured out my issues, here are my findings:

- I have found that the GeoServer is not recognizing the objectid as primary keys in the spatial views we have created. This is problematic for 3rd party clients that are specifically looking for column to generate the FeatureId, an OGC spec. Specifically ArcGIS Pro’s WFS On Demand mode.
- If you want to ensure that a primary key is going to be used for a spatial view, you it is best to set up this metadata table.
  The metadata table must include all the fields mentioned in the create script from the link provided, or else GeoServer will bark and will not use the designated field as a primary key.
- When setting the metadata table in the GeoServer store settings, you must include the schema name: {schema_name}.{table_name}
- The metadata table does not need to have the same name as described in the docs
- The metadata table does not need to be in the same schema as the schema you are connecting too.
- I thought that GeoServer would just hit this table on every query, but it seems to cache the table schema internally. Therefore:
- After making any changes to the metadata schema, you must go back into the store and hit Save again for GeoServer to “rehydrate” it’s internal settings.
- Store will need to be “resaved” any time a new record is added to the metadata table as well.