# Getting GeoServer to use custom primary key values when inserting features using WFS

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t, insert

When I use WFS to insert features, I want the primary key value to take the attribute value I set, but GeoServer automatically generates the primary key value and ignores the primary key value I set.
Here is my geometry table:

```
create table test(a int primary key, b int, c geometry(Point, 4326));
```

**I've tried the following:**
I am following directions [GeoServer docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html) to create the primary key metadata table,

but, it doesn't work.
Here is my primary key metadata table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.gt_pk_metadata (
  table_schema VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  table_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  pk_column VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  pk_column_idx INTEGER,
  pk_policy VARCHAR(32),
  pk_sequence VARCHAR(64),
  unique (table_schema, table_name, pk_column),
  check (pk_policy in ('sequence', 'assigned', 'autoincrement'))
);

INSERT INTO gt_pk_metadata (
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  pk_column,
  pk_policy
) VALUES (
  'public',
  'test',
  'a',
  'assigned'
);
```

The WFS request as follows:

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Insert>
    <test xmlns="http://geoserver/postgres">
      <c><Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326"><pos srsDimension="2">109.47051452397488 32.96654482702854</pos></Point>
      </c>
      <a>123</a>
      <b>321</b>
    </test>
  </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

However, the primary key field still does not take the value I set.

On the GeoServer configuration in store, "Expose primary keys" has been enabled, "Primary key metadata table" is left blank.
I tried to set "Primary key metadata table" to *public.gt_pk_metadata*, but still no help.
I also tried the following methods in the similar question: [Getting GeoServer primary key metadata table working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418489/getting-geoserver-primary-key-metadata-table-working)

I'm confused about how to set the primary key value I want.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: In general the actual value of your fid is irrelevant - if you need specific values to be stored then use a normal attribute not the fid

Comment: You must set "Primary key metadata table" to public.gt_pk_metadata, otherwise it will not be read, as GeoServer does not look for it. Which database are you using? Where does it fail? On insertion or re-read? Can you set up a metadatatable entry  for an existing table and get an arbitrary column as FID in a WFS read request?

Comment: I use Postgresql. I have tried to set "Primary key metadata table" to public.gt_pk_metadata, but it didn't work. When I insert a feature, the Geoserver does not use the primary key field attribute value I set.  Instead, Geoserver automatically generates a primary key value and modify the field attribute value. I need to use an attribute field as the primary key.

Comment: What kind of FID do you get on a WFS read when you set column "b" as primary key in metadata table? If the FID is a guid you have no primary key at all, which means that the metadata table has no effect at all. If it is the same int that is in column "b" at least the reading part works, which is a good start. If it is the value in column "a" Geoserver assumes that the column set to PK in database is FID.  According to documentation Geoserver assumes that a column with autoincrement is FID, but test just to be sure that is not picks that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck. I have tested your setup and have managed to get pk_policy =*sequence* to work as expected. All other values for pk_policy yields in autoincrement. I draw the conclusion that my metadata table is correctly set up, but either GeoServer has a bug, or the documentation is incorrect.

Also I found this: https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/37386688/
basically what it says it that someone asks the same as you and gets a response from one of the main developers of GeoServer that it is probably not possible. But I do not agree with the argumentation that it would be because the column is not added to the insert statement, as the key columns are added later in the same function.

In this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713831/geoserver-configuring-a-primary-key-metadata-table-for-pk-assignment-using-a-po
A workaround is proposed, which I have tested and it works for geoserver 2.20.2 using the following statement:

```xml
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Insert idgen="UseExisting">
        <sf:test xmlns:sf="http://localhost:8008/sf" fid="999">
            <sf:c>
                <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857">
                    <pos srsDimension="2">2312896.5286310725 8111449.527554644</pos>
                </Point>
            </sf:c>
            <sf:a>909</sf:a>
            <sf:b>120</sf:b>
          </sf:test>
    </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

It works for at least wfs 1.1.0, but requires that you can set the *idgen* attribute `<Insert idgen="UseExisting">`and the *fid* attribute `<sf:test xmlns:sf="http://localhost:8008/sf" fid="999">`. In the example above the feature will get a=999 in the database. The statement that sets a=909 is ignored in favour of the fid statement.

Comment: This method works for me. It would be great if Geoserver could fix the problem with the primary key metadata table.